# In Gmail Contacts how do you scroll down a list of contacts that's larger than your vertical space?

Tags: gmail, contacts, user-interface

In Gmail Contacts, some of my lists are pretty large, so when I choose them the list goes past the page.  There isn't a scrollbar in that section, so I don't know how to access the lower part of the list.

Any ideas?

Here's a pic of the bottom of the screen (with names munged):

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/9297/gmailcontacts.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/9297/gmailcontacts.png)

**EDIT:**  The latest version of Gmail Contacts (rolled out Summer 2010) fixes this problem.

Comment: What browser?  Not seeing this in IE/Chrome/Firefox on Win7.

Comment: @rchern, IE8, pic posted now.

Comment: Strange.  The only time I do not get a scrollbar in the middle panel that you show is if I first load a small group that does not require a scrollbar, and then resize my browser to a smaller height.  A scrollbar doesn't get added in the middle pane, though there is one for the browser window itself.  If I then load a larger group in that small browser size, I'll have a scrollbar in the middle pane and for the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can report the problem [here.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=direct&hl=en&group=)

Comment: Thanks, I always have such a hard time finding that page.  Now I'll always be able to go to this answer to find it fast.